# ReverseMap on open generics

Tags: automapper, automapper-4

I'm using AutoMapper 4.1.1 (latest stable release on NuGet), and it looks like using `ReverseMap` on an open generic `CreateMap` doesn't work.

Sample program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(A<>), typeof(B<>)).ReverseMap(); // Doesn't work.
    Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(A<>), typeof(B<>)); // Works.
    Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(B<>), typeof(A<>)); // Works.

    Mapper.CreateMap<AData, BData>().ReverseMap();

    var b = new B<BData> { Data = new BData { Info = "Test" } };
    var a = Mapper.Map<A<AData>>(b);
}

public class A<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

public class B<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

public class AData
{
    public string Info { get; set; }
}

public class BData
{
    public string Info { get; set; }
}
```

If I use the line with `ReverseMap` on it, I get the following exception:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types:
>   B`1 -> A`1
>   ConsoleApplication64.Program+B`1[[ConsoleApplication64.Program+BData, ConsoleApplication64, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> ConsoleApplication64.Program+A`1[[ConsoleApplication64.Program+AData, ConsoleApplication64, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
>
> Destination path:
>   A`1
>
> Source value:
>   ConsoleApplication64.Program+B`1[ConsoleApplication64.Program+BData]

Am I doing something wrong, or can we actually not use `ReverseMap` with open generics?